# Passing a variable string to LIKE in SQLite (Python)

Tags: python, string, sqlite, variables, sql-like

So I've been looking around but I can't seem to find answer to a seemingly simple and probably commonly asked question. In SQLite, I have a query that I want to pass via user defined search text.

```
search = xChatMessageSplit[2]

c.execute("SELECT * FROM captured WHERE Nick=? AND Name LIKE '%search%'",(xChatNick,search))
```

Obviously the syntax or whatever is incorrect since I'm getting errors, but I want to basically allow users to define a search term for string, "search." How would I go about doing this? I tried using REGEXP but I can't seem to figure out how to define the function so I figured I'd just go with LIKE since it's already implemented into SQLite3

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `?` to show where the parameter's value will be used.

```
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM captured
             WHERE Nick=?
             AND Name LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')""", (xChatNick,search))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying do this all day long